# Are there sequences which its partial sum is unbounded?

Tags: analysis

In particular, I am reading about Dirichlet criterion on sequences...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

I noticed that in the wiki page ("Statement" section), the condition on sequence $b_n$ is basically "partial sum of sequence needed to be bounded".

But I somehow think that this requirement is redundant, since partial sum is already consist of "finite terms", am I right?

Comment: No the sequence of partial sums has to be bounded, look at $b_n=n$, the sequence of partial sums is obviously not bounded.

Comment: However my thought is that, after you give me what n is (where the partial sum chopped), I can give you what M (the bound value) is, isn't it?

Comment: There is no difference between the definition of boundedness for sequences or sequences of partial sums(since they are pretty much sequences). A partial sum is bounded if there is ONE $M$ such that $\sum_{1}^k b_n< M$ for every $k$

Comment: I see, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Even simpler: taking $b_n=1$ for all $n$ produces a sequence whose partial sums are not bounded. Another example, that doesn't actually tend to infinity, is $b_n = (-1)^n \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$.